# Swift, Parse - Unable to search array to check if string is contained in array

Tags: swift, parse-platform

```
  let uuid = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString


    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count")
    object.addObject(uuid, forKey: "likedBy")
    object.saveInBackground()

    sender.enabled = false

    object["likedBy"].whereKey(uuid, notContainedIn: object["likedBy"] as Array)
```

Creating a like button where user clicks like button and the user ID object gets added to the Parse array called "likedBy." I want to set it up where when the user clicks *like* the code verifies that the user ID isn't in the "likedBy" array and correspondingly disables or executes code to insert user ID into the array. I've tried whereKey and contains and both seem to crash.

What does work: the object does add the uuid into the likedBy array however since the user can click the like button an infinite amount of times the user ID keeps getting added to the array.

What doesn't: Cannot search array for user ID value. Crashes when using contains or WhereKey Equal to as suggested in Parse docs.